# Fixed range and fill missing values in Apache eCharts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to display monthly values in eCharts according to the following conditions:

- fill missing values (e.g. display an empty bar for missing months within the interval)
- start from a specific month
- end on a specific month

Example of input data

```js
let x = ['2019-10', '2020-02', '2020-03']
let y = [1403, 938, 1105]
```

Example of desired output:
[image]

I've tried using the following options for the xAxis, to no avail:

```js
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: 'YYYY-MM',
    },
    min: '2019-05',
    max: '2020-05',
    data: x
  }
```

JSFiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/pewx61gz/3/

Answer (score 1):

Echarts has few options to obtain desired. I don't know all possible options and prefer most simplest and obviously defined because if you want to change chart behavior programmatically you will get hell with option dependencies of something that you don't know yet.

I'm a bit [change your example](http://jsfiddle.net/ngeb7qod/):

```js
let x = ['2019-07-01','2019-08-01', '2019-10-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01']
let y = ['-', '-', 1403, 938, 1105]

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
  title: {
    text: 'ECharts'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    axisLabel: {
      //formatter: 'YYYY-MM',
      formatter: val => {
        var date = new Date(val).toISOString();
        return date.slice(0,7);
      },
    },
    //min: '2019-05',
    //max: '2020-05',
    data: x
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: y
  }]
}

myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.7.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

P.S. `'-'` — it's conventional way to say "no data".